# String to int conversion bug?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python “is” operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

in python 2.6.6 when I use int() to convert a string to a number the below code doesn't behave correct if the string is 257 or larger.

```
curr = int("256")  
myint = int("256")  
if curr is myint:  
    print("true")  
else:  
    print("false")
```

this returns true which is correct

```
curr = int("257")  
myint = int("257")  
if curr is myint:  
    print("true")  
else:  
    print("false")
```

this returns false ???

Answer (score 6):

You should not use `is` to compare integers. Use `==` instead.

`is` should only be used to test if two variables are pointing to the same object. In Python, small numbers are interred and you *often* get the same object for the same int literal, but not always and not for larger numbers.

Comment: Exactly right. Example:     >>> int("256") is int("256")
     True
     >>> int("257") is int("257") 
     False
     >>> int("257") == int("257")
     True

Answer (score 4):

That's because all integers from `-5` to `256` are cached, so you're going to get `is` as `True` for them.

Read [Python integer objects implementation](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `==` operator to compare integers, and use `is` when comparing to None or same objects.

```
>>> a = 257
>>> b = 257
>>> a is b
False
>>> a == b
True
```